# execvp() - exit() return value in function

Tags: c, error-handling, exit, execvp

I have been fighting with the following concept lately and I am still unable to understand it. I have this block of code

```
int foo(int f){
    int fail = 10;  //some random initialization value
    int status;
    pid_t child_pid;
    child_pid = fork();

    if(child_pid == 0) {
        /* This is done by the child process. */

        if (execvp(tokens2[0], tokens2)<0){
            fail =1;
            perror(tokens2[0]); 
            exit(1);
        }
    }else if(child_pid<0){
        perror("Fork failed");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        waitpid(child_pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
    }

    //handle execvp error return value
    if (fail == 1){
        return -1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
    
}
```

It does not make a lot of sense (don't mind `tokens2[]` array, it is declared properly and it works just fine) because it is on an abstract form in order for it to be audible and easy to understand. The question is: what is the output of function `foo`? This is what I have come to get so far:

> 1)If `execvp` succeeds, it does not return any value. If it fails it returns `-1` (I think this return value does not have to do anything with my `foo` function).
>
> 2)`exit(1)` kills the child process and returns the control flow to the parent.

In my understanding, if `execvp` succeeds, the `foo` should return `-1`(according to variable `fail`), if it fails it should return `0`, but that is not what my `printf` checks on the main function show. Actually the outcome is always the opposite of what I expect.

PS: I found something about `execvp` error handling using the good old *shelf-pipe* trick but it is too noisy for me. I want a simpler way to handle the error.

Comment: I have just found out that when `exit(1)` is called the child process is destroyed and so are the alterations on the variables that took place in it. Could that be the answer?

Comment: You really don't want the `WUNTRACED` option in `waitpid()`.  Not in the code you show, anyway.  A job control shell might use it, but a shell doing so would also pay attention to the return value and status information.  Use `0` for the last argument to `waitpid()` unless you want to see whether there's a terminated process, in which case `WNOHANG` becomes relevant and useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is: what is the output of function foo?

You seem to be asking what is the *return value* of `foo()`.  "Output" usually refers to data written to the terminal or an external file.  But the question remains: in which process?  Supposing that the `fork()` succeeds, you then have two virtually identical processes, both executing `foo()`.

> > ```
> > 1)If execvp succeeds, it does not return any value.
> > ```

If `execvp()` succeeds, it does not return *at all*.

> > If it fails it returns -1 (I think this return value does not have to do anything
> >     with my foo function).

Yes.  Only your child process executes `execvp()`, however, and in the event that it returns, the process ends up calling `exit()`.

> > ```
> > 2)exit(1) kills the child process and returns the control flow to the parent.
> > ```

That terminates the process before it ever returns from `foo()`, so in the child process `foo()` never returns, whether `execvp` succeeds or not.  Control *does not* return to the parent.  Forking a process is not at all the same as calling a function.  The parent can learn about the child's exit code via the `waitpid()` call it makes.

**In the parent**, if the `fork()` fails then that process, too, calls `exit()` and therefore does not return from `foo()`.  Supposing that the `fork()` succeeds, on the other hand, the parent waits until the child terminates.  The child is a separate process, with its own copy of all the variables, so whatever it may have done to its copy of `fail` has no effect on the parent.  That is, forking a child process is not like launching a thread in the same process, either.

Since the parent does not itself modify `fail`, it still has its initial value, 10, if it reaches

> ```
>     if (fail == 1){
> ```

10 != 1, so if `foo()` does return then it returns 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In which case does -1 return?

Comment: As I said, @johngonidelis, "if `foo()` does return then it returns 0." In ***no*** case does the given `foo` return -1.

Comment: What if the `fail` variable is replaced by the `status` variable? Would I be able to detect if `execvp()` succeeded or no?

Comment: Not directly, @johngonidelis, no.  But in the event that the child exits normally -- whether or not its `execvp` succeeds -- the `status` set by `waitpid` encodes its *exit status*, among other things.  You may be able to choose an exist status in the `execlp` failure case that would never be emitted by the program you're trying to `exec`, and in that way distinguish between the two cases.  Details of examining the status are presented on [the `waitpid()` manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid).

Answer (score 0):

`execvp` *overwrites your whole process* with the one you're `exec`ing.

If `execvp` succeeds, the `fail` variable no longer exists in the child. The `foo` function no longer exists in the child. The function that called `foo` no longer exists in the child. If `execvp` succeeds then the child is now running a *different program's* `main` function.

Eventually that program will exit, and then the child process exits. It never goes back to your program. (That's why you need to create a separate process to call `execvp` in - if you used the original process, you'd never get it back)

Comment: The`fork()` is called inside the `foo` function. I don't think that `foo` function "no longer exists" when child exits.

Comment: Then you are wrong, @johngonidelis.  If the child's `execvp` call succeeds then indeed `foo` no longer exists in that process, unless whichever program replaces the original one has *its own* `foo`.  And even in that case, execution would still commence in `main`, not in `foo`.

Comment: @johngonidelis It doesn't exist in the child. It still exists in the master because they are separate.